# How to make database on ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have just created the project on ruby on rails. I also generated a controller with an instruction on bash, "rails g controller home".
However, I didn't make database. How can I generate database? Please inform me how to make database.
Thank you.

Comment: And I have asked first time. So, please correct grammar disorders.

Comment: Pease read [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a database table by typing:

```
rails g model myTableName
```

Because your starting out new i think it would be best to try something like:

```
rails g scaffold Post name:string content:text
```

This will link the controller, the model(which is the database) and the views together, giving you a better understanding on how the MVC structure works in rails.